# how to execute a server script and then pass the information to the client in meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm working with two files [root]/test.js with a calling function

```
Meteor.call("getUsers", "Juan P", function (error, result) {
           console.log(result);
      });
```

and another file [root]/server/secret.js with this definition

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
      var getUsers = function(name) {
           return "Hi. I'm " + name;
      };
}
```

however the function getUsers is getting undefined, I really appreciate any help or hint about fixing this problem! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define it as a Meteor.method

```
Meteor.methods({
    getUsers: function (name) {
       return "Hi. I'm " + name;
    }
});
```

Also, when you put your code in /server/ folder you don't have to check Meteor.isServer anymore, it makes it a little cleaner. Same goes for /client/ and Meteor.isClient.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods):

```
Meteor.methods({
  getUsers: function (name) {
    return "Hi. I'm " + name;
  }
});
```

And you don't need `isServer`, because everything in folder `server` runs on the server.